# How to save file to disk using drag-and-drop on web page

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've been trying for months to drag a file to a drop area on a web page and save that file to disk. None of the examples I found actually save the file.

The code below is where I am at the moment. I can get the file at the line " var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();" and the console.log()s show the correct file type and name. I can use JSP if that helps, but assigning the dragged file to a type="file" form input gives me a security violation error. I need to know what to do where I have "Now what? Save file!" I've snagged the basic code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    console.log('File(s) dropped');
    ev.preventDefault();

    if (ev.dataTransfer.items)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++)
        {
            if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file')       // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
            {
                var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();

                console.log('type: ' + file.type);
                console.log('file[' + i + '].name = ' + file.name + ", type: " + file.type);
                // Now What? Save File to disk!
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        console.log('dataTransfer');
        for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++)
        {
            console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name);
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag some image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Actual results is that the console.log() statements show the correct type and file name, but I have no information on what to do to actually save the file to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `Javascript` for you security matter unless you use `NodeJs` or another back end language.

Comment: I'm using JSP. I can successfully use the usual multipart/DiskFileItemFactory, but I'm wanting to do drag-and-drop instead. Can I not do something with JSP for drag-and-drop? Since I am apparently able to dataTransfer.getAsFile(), it seems like I should then be able to do something with the retrieved file. Why would the developer.mozilla.org example use javascript if it can't be done with javascript?